# How to Install Octave in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source, install

The new GNU Octave 4.0.1 was released March 23, 2016. 
I would like to find some standard way to install it in El Capitan (mine OS X 10.11.3) because it has significantly better support in some functions than Matlab, discussed in the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36084829/54964). 
I do `brew search octave` and get

```
homebrew/science/octave    Caskroom/cask/octave       Caskroom/cask/xoctave
```

where one of the first two should be a correct one.
The project's homepage [support](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html) for OS X is down [here](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X) about *installing Octave on OS X systems*. 
There is also ruby's way of installing Octave described in the thread [How to install Octave on OS X (Yosemite)](http://adampash.com/how-to-install-octave/) but for Yosemite. 
I would like to find some standard way of getting Octave for OS X.

I do successfully `brew update` and `brew upgrade` before the commands.
My Homebrew is 0.9.5 (git revision 80d1; last commit 2016-03-24). 
[user1256923](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232313/15504). I run `brew info octave` but I get

```
Error: No available formula with the name "octave"
```

---

How can you install Octave in some standard way for El Capitan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MacPorts ( http://macports.org/ ), with insight from instructions at http://blog.hani-ibrahim.de/en/octave4-mac-os-x-el-capitan-install.html (as well as http://blog.hani-ibrahim.de/en/octave-mac-os-x-el-capitan-install.html and http://blog.hani-ibrahim.de/en/octave4-upgrade-via-macports.html) as well as the Octave wiki at http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X#MacPorts

It seems as though MacPort's default `atlas` variant doesn't play nice with Octave, and `arpac` and `qrupdate` also have issues with their default installion, needing specific "variants" to properly build. Basically to get all of Octave 4 running, I did:

```
sudo port install atlas +gcc5
sudo port install arpack -accelerate+atlas+gfortran 
sudo port install qrupdate -accelerate+atlas+gcc5
sudo port install octave -gcc5+gfortran-accelerate+atlas+docs+fltk+graphicsmagick+java-gui-metis-qtgui+app+qt4gui+sound
```

Probably some of the octave variant flags are unneeded for some people, but I went with the options suggested by hani-ibrahim.de and it works for me to get command line Octave up and running, as well as giving a nifty Octave.app in the /Applications/MacPorts directory.

If you need Java support with the Java variant (+java) as above, you probably need a JDK (Java Development Kit) to get the necessary command line suff for that magic to work, so go to ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index.html ) for a download. Maybe the smaller JRE (Java Runtime Environment) would be sufficient, but I have installed the full JDK. Omitting the (+java) flag removes this requirement.

I just tested it (2016/09/01) on Mac OS X 10.11.6 and was able to intall via MacPorts with no errors, ending up with atlas @3.10.2_2, arpack @3.3.0_3, qrupdate @1.1.2_4 and octave @4.0.3_0

On about 2016/12/05, with just the xcode command line tools installed (not the full XCode), I was able to use the above to install on macOS 10.12.1 Sierra: arpack @3.3.0_3, atlas @3.10.2_2, qrupdate @1.1.2_4, and octave @4.2.0_1. I initially was not able to get 4.2.0_0 installed, but 0_1 finally did. The installation ended with the warning "unless octave is run with –no-gui-libs, graphics_toolkit(“fltk”) will cause a crash" but I have not investigated this issue.

Comment: In MacOS Sierra, this doesn't work, I had to run: `cd $(brew --repo); git fetch; git reset --hard origin/master` and after that: `brew install homebrew/science/octave` and it's working now, more infor here: https://twitter.com/MacHomebrew/status/763686348041641984

Comment: Hi @calbertts did you mean to put this comment in the "homebrew" answer?

Comment: I've tried with all the answers, and this one worked fine until the  latest command, that's why I'm sharing what I had to do to make it work.

Comment: Hi @calbertts, MacHomebrew and MacPorts are totally seperate package managers, so invoking "brew install" to fix a non working "port octave" is a bit like saying "The instructions on how to fix the squeeky screen door with the Philips screwdriver did not quite work for me. What did work was to knock a hole in the wall on the other side of the house and mount a different screen door there using a Robertson screwdriver". If you installed Octave using brew, perhaps you might want to uninstall the MacPorts stuff to eliminate duplication or possible conflicts/confusion when updating or invoking.

Answer (score 6):

From my homebrew:

```
brew info octave
homebrew/science/octave: stable 4.0.0 (bottled), HEAD
high-level interpreted language for numerical computing  
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index.html
Not installed
```

and

```
brew cask info octave
octave: 3.8.2-1
Octave
https://gnu.org/software/octave/
Not installed
```

`xoctave` is a gui which I suspect is independent.  I'd use `homebrew` for the installation.

FWIW the [Octave wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X) it explains what to do:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew update && brew upgrade --all
brew install octave
```

Comment: With mine I have to run `brew install homebrew/science/octave`

Comment: This is because you didn't tap homebrew/science

Answer (score 2):

if you have already installed gcc...

```
sudo chown -R (username):admin /usr/local/lib/gcc/
```

and

```
brew install octave
```

after this, you make cross fingers...

Comment: "Make cross fingers" love it.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Octave.app](http://octave-app.org/) when searching for resolution to problems related to the homebrew installation of `octave` on High Sierra.

The Octave.app has at macOS based testing suite. And when needed, has even applied patches to address [upstream code issues](https://github.com/octave-app/octave-app-bundler/issues/13).

*`Octave.app` is based on the homebrew build, just with the value add of macOS specific testing, bundling, … and patching.*

Indeed, Octave.app even had fixed the very Qt issue(s?) that appeared to be causing problems with the homebrew release in my case. Since Octave.app patched the upstream Qt issues which Homebrew had not, I unlinked the homebrew version and installed Octave.app.

```
# if octave exists from either regular Homebrew or dpo/openblas formulae 
brew unlink octave
```

[Octave.app](http://octave-app.org/) launches OK in GUI mode. [Octave.app installs from a dmg](http://octave-app.org/Download.html). Thus, neither `Homebrew` nor `MacPorts` are required.

I also added the following to the bash profile:

```
##############
### Octave ###
##############
### http://octave-app.org/
alias octave="open -a \"Octave\""
```